# Linux создание мягких ссылок на директорию

Tags: linux, xampp

Существует папка под root правами htdocs в директории xampp,  и сам xampp запускается от имени root.

Пробовал менять права на xampp panel, но приводит к тому, что программа просто перестаёт работать.

И пришёл к выводу не относящуюся к этому решению но

Как сделать символьную ссылку на htdocs, чтобы она отображалась на рабочем столе?

Но если есть решение как запускать xampp не от root - подскажите плииз.

Comment: *как запускать xampp не от root* — зачем?

Comment: как бы напрягает не много - всегда сначала писать gksu а потом только открывается panel xampp - смена прав не помогает - точнее перестаёт работать

Comment: При чем тут вообще root или не-root, если проблема была в символической ссылке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как сделать символьную ссылку на htdocs что бы она отображалась на рабочем столе?

```
$ ln -s /путь/к/htdocs "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)/"
```

здесь команда `xdg-user-dir DESKTOP` служит для получения пути к каталогу, который выполняет роль *desktop* у пользователя, выполнившего эту команду. подробнее см. в `man xdg-user-dir`.

кавычки же нужны для корректной обработки случаев, когда имя каталога содержит пробелы (`рабочий стол`).

Comment: а за что мне там минусов налепили ??

Comment: скорее всего, за довольно сумбурную формулировку.

Comment: я точно же не знал как задать вопрос ! но если человек (к примеру Вы) разбирается то поймёт - мне тоже много чего не надо объяснять и если не вижу грамотного вопроса не бегу ставить минус - в принципе мне до Лампочки